# why jQuery filter function not working through table body & row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, filter

[image]I am trying to search through an address book made in JS and jQuery and have tried most available pattern options to filter tbody and tr through below ready() of search but it's not working, could you please have a look and let me know where I am going wrong. Below is my html and JS code, I'm working in repl.it 
Thank you.

---

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>repl.it</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container">
        <header>
          <h1>Address Book</h1>
          <hr />
        </header>
        <table id='table1' class="table">
          <input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
          <br><br>
          <thead> 
            <tr>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th>Phone</th>
              <th>Address</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          </tbody>
          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <input id='firstName' class='form-control' type="text" placeholder ='Name'>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input id='lastName' class='form-control' type="text" placeholder ='Surname'>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input id='phone' class='form-control' type="text" placeholder ='Contact Number'>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input id='address' class='form-control' type="text" placeholder ='Full Postal Address'>
              </td> 
              <td>
                <div class="text-center">
                  <button id='add' class='btn btn-block' >Add</button>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
        </table>
      </div>  

      <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

---

### JS CODE

```
var adBook = (function () {
  // default fields for understanding
  var pplDetails = [{
    firstName: 'Sam',
    lastName: 'Smith',
    phone: '004477995544',
    address: '33 jump st, London'
  }];

  //variables declaration
  var table = $('#table1');
  var $tbody = table.find('tbody');
  var $firstName = table.find('#firstName');
  var $lastName = table.find('#lastName');
  var $phone = table.find('#phone');
  var $address = table.find('#address');
  var $button = table.find('#add');
  var $btnRemove = table.find('#remove');
  var $input = table.find(".edit");


  //events calls
  $button.on('click', adPerson);
  table.on('click', '#remove', delPerson);
  console.log($input);
  build();



  //function to create new table data
  function build() {
    $tbody.html('');
    var length = pplDetails.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      table.prepend('<tr><td><input type="text" value="' + pplDetails[i].firstName + '" ></td> <td><input type="text" value="' + pplDetails[i].lastName + '" ></td> <td><input type="text" value="' + pplDetails[i].phone + '" ></td> <td><input type="text" value="' + pplDetails[i].address + '" ></td> <td> <button id="remove" class="btn btn-block">Del</button></td></tr>');
    }
  }

  //function to add persons details
  function adPerson() {
    var data = {
      firstName: $firstName.val(),
      lastName: $lastName.val(),
      phone: $phone.val(),
      address: $address.val()
    };
    pplDetails.push(data);
    $firstName.val('');
    $lastName.val('');
    $phone.val('');
    build()
  }

  //function to delete details
  function delPerson(event) {
    var element = event.target.closest('tr');
    var i = table.find('td').index(element);
    pplDetails.splice(i, 1);
    build();
  }

  return {
    adPerson: adPerson,
    delPerson: delPerson
  };



})();


//Search bar
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function () {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('tbody tr').filter(function () {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Where is jQuery filter function not working? What is the expected behaviour? Please add the small demo for only where the issue is occurring not the full app code.

Comment: you're including two **jquery libs**

Comment: @palaѕн after adding some record to the table when I search thas what happens, pls see pic, rather it should be filtering and show search matched result.

Comment: Hey @RoyBogado even if I take out one jquery lib, that still makes no difference

Answer (score 0):

A few issues seen in your code.
First thing as palasH pointed out there are two jquery inclusions in the HTML as below.

```
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

and

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Your `tbody` tag is empty as it is given as below.

```
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
```

The whole table contents - that is the `tr` rows are within `tfoot` tags. Hence `$('tbody tr').filter()` will fail as it can't find `tr` within `tbody` tags.

Please correct the above and check.

Comment: Hey @die-Bugger, 
I have already mentioned in comments that even if you take off jquery  2nd lib that wont make any difference.
2- jQuery is making table conents of tbody dynamically.

Comment: Would you not use `$tbody.html()` rather than `table.prepend`? That way, your `tbody` gets populated correctly, so that the search picks correctly the data from `'tbody tr'`